# How to track explorer.exe crashes in win8.1x64

Tags: windows-explorer, debug

I've recently installed win8.1x64 on my laptop.

Problem is: Explorer keeps crashing everyday and re-sorting my desktop items, and I can't find out why.

Things I tried:
Added a registry entry where crashdumps are saved everytime something crashes, this is the result:

[image: http://puu.sh/hFkop/94b7440fee.png]

Then I downloaded windbg to try and sort out what could cause this and this opened the dmp files with the following:

```
----------------------------------------------------------

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\CrashDumps\explorer.exe.7480.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Version 9600 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Built by: 6.3.9600.17031 (winblue_gdr.140221-1952)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Thu May  7 23:01:13.000 2015 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:38:02.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...................................................
Loading unloaded module list
........................................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1d38.17c0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not     available)
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for     ntdll.dll - 
<Unloaded_QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4.dll>+0x265fe:
00000000`509065fe ??              ???

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I still can't figure out what's happening. Any hints on this issue?

EDIT:
After following commentary instructions I've come up with this data on windbg

```
---------------------

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
You can run '.symfix; .reload' to try to fix the symbol path and load     symbols.

FAULTING_MODULE: 00007ffb083b0000 ntdll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50d3fca7

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced     memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced     memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000509065fe

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000000509065fe 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4!unloaded+265fe
00000000`509065fe ??              ???

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4!unloaded+265fe
00000000`509065fe ??              ???

APP:  explorer.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

-----------------
```

This is way beyong my knowledge. I have absolute no idea on what could be causing this crashes. But since there's "core" written there, does it have something to do with the cpu?

Comment: Does it happen in safe mode?

Comment: Do this on windbg in order: ".symfix" "!analyze -v" and attach the result here. Or, it'll be even better if you can somehow share the actual dump file.

Comment: Here it is  http://www.filedropper.com/explorerexe1116 But I'd also like to learn how to track what causes this problems too. Thank you

Comment: Still want to know about safe mode and/or your use of Autoruns to control what is loaded so only the absolute minimum is loaded.

Comment: This is my startup http://puu.sh/hFo1e/9177310d05.png http://puu.sh/hFo0B/7e11c5dff2.png  But it doesn't crash on startup, it crashes while in use. I can't try it on safe mode, because I'd still be clueless on what's causing it.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the question, I have absolute no idea onwhat's causing the crashes.

Comment: @ScottRhee I've updated the question, I have absolute no idea onwhat's causing the crashes.

Comment: Can you spend some time to format your question?  I was extremely specific about the information I wanted.  I don't need to know what your startup is I just want to know if it happens in a very minimal boot.

Comment: Yes I will, give me a sec (I never formated before but i'll try

Comment: @Ramhound The explorer crashes happens randomly, so it will take time to test

Comment: nice to hear that used my .reg files to generate dumps. Use this .reg to disable the dump creation: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=128fc518635be2dc&id=128FC518635BE2DC%21672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your updates, it seemed that one of AutoDesk products caused the issue.

"QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4" is one of the signatures of their libraries. How to know? I just Googled it.

There is a very similar topic here on AutoDesk forum:
http://feedback.autodesk.com/cloudservices/topics/autodesk_desktop_companion_cause_explorer_app_to_crash

I have no idea about AutoDesk products, but probably there is a sort of monitoring feature which is attached to Windows Explorer and this sort of Windows Explorer extensions can be detached easily (not always though). At the end of the page I linked there is a way to turn off AutoDesk 360 only which seemed to cause your crash.

> This will help you only if you don't use Autodesk 360:
>
> Never ever uninstall it cause this will cause you problems with all
> other Autodesk products.
>
> A) Disable 360. From 360 settings disable:
>
> (x) Start Autodesk 360 when I log into Windows.
>
> and from AutoCAD settings disable:
>
> (x) Enable Automatic Sync  (x) Sync my Settings with the Cloud.
>
> B) Go to Program files\Autodesk -or Program files(x86)\Autodesk-
> folder and search for the "QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4.dll"
>
> Best guess that you will find two of them. Just rename both to
> "QtCore_Ad_SyncNs_4.dll.BAK" or whatever you like.

Or, if you don't use AutoDesk products, you can just simply uninstall them. Probably the crash will go away if you do so.

If you want to completely fix the problem, it's better to contact AutoDesk product provider and give them the dump you've got.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's the first time i've used a crash dmp on this format so I had no idea what to search for in that dmp file. Will take note and correct other problems if they happen ;)